# Code . not working in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Have added C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio to the path, restarted computer, verified that path includes C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio. I still get an error on running code . as

```
'code' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable 
program or batch file.

System specs: Windows 10, VS 2017
```

Regards

Comment: What is the exact command you are running? What are you trying to do? You're just typing `code` into the command prompt and... expecting what to happen?

Comment: Code and Visual Studio are 2 different applications. If you have Visual Studio I am not sure you want Visual Studio Code.

Comment: thanks for clarifying @drescherjm

Answer (score 0):

code . is a command for visual studio code, if i'm right you installed Visual Studio, no visual studio code, the path should be Microsoft VS Code.

if it is Code what you installed, maybe you should check the envrioment variables.

if you have not installed VS code go [Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

Comment: thanks. I installed VS, not VS Code, before this answer I thought they are same.